# Social networking sites's login is happening via own Application

Tags: android

I have a activity in which a Dialog box opens showing list of Social network icons. Clicking on the icon, it will open the site in the same app rather than browser but problem is there when we hit login after entering username and password, it shows exception as follow:

```
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@41c59680 is not valid; is your activity running?
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:513)
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at android.webkit.WebView.onSavePassword(WebView.java:1402)
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:442)
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-27 14:16:14.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4052):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-27 14:16:14.605: I/dalvikvm(4052): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-27 14:16:14.613: I/dalvikvm(4052): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-27 14:16:16.273: I/Process(4052): Sending signal. PID: 4052 SIG: 9
```

and here is my code:

```
public class ShareActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    //public static ShareActivity context;
    WebView wv;
    boolean land_scape=false;
    ProgressDialog pdlg;
    String links[]= new String[]{"Facebook","Twitter","Google Plus","Pintrest"};
    ListView lv1;
    Dialog dialog ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
           setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
           land_scape=true;

        }
        else {
           setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
           land_scape=false;
        }
      setContentView(R.layout.share_layout);    
      //context=this;

      wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
      wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      dialog = new Dialog(ShareActivity.this.getParent());
      dialog.setTitle("Please select");

      dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
      dialog.setContentView(R.layout.share_list);
      lv1=(ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.listShare);
      lv1.setAdapter(new CustomShareAdapter(this,links));
      lv1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
      dialog.show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        switch(arg2)
        {
        case 0:  
            wv.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
            break;
        case 1: 
            wv.loadUrl("https://mobile.twitter.com/login");
            break;

        case 2: 
            wv.loadUrl("http://www.plus.google.com");       
            break;
        case 3: 
            wv.loadUrl("http://www.pinterest.com");         
            break;
        }
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        dialog.dismiss();
    }


    @Override
     public void onResume()
     {

            //Determine screen size
            if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &      Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {     
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Large screen set to landscape",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
                land_scape=true;


            }
            else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &      Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {     
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Normal sized screen set to portrait" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
                land_scape=false;

            } 
            else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &      Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {     
               // Toast.makeText(this, "Small sized screen set to portrait " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
                land_scape=false;
            }
            else {
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Screen size is neither large, normal or small" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                land_scape=false;
            }
            super.onResume();
     }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent backIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(backIntent);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

2nd QUestion: it also shows empty screen which i have not set. 
I have searched alot on this regard. Please help me.

Comment: This error generally occurs when you try to work with a dialog after activity is finished

Comment: @ShreyaShah please suggest me some solution.

Comment: Check in onDestroy():   if (dialog.isShowing()) then
   dialog.dismiss();

Comment: for which question are you suggesting me this answer? if it is for second question then On back button pressed it shows blank screen and again pressing the back button it leads me to the main Activity. but i want it to happen on first press.

Comment: This answer is for that application crash. And I think it can solve second too, if the back button issue was due to dialog. Let me knw what happens after trying it

Comment: @ShreyaShah it does not work and logcat is showing the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your dialog with this code:

```
dialog = new Dialog(this);
```

I think getParent() returns something not usable to you, as all you need is your current activity.

Comment: i can't because this all is happening in tab activity. It did so, it would work. So any other solution please?

Comment: @Rohit OK, so how about keeping your original line of code, but create and show the dialog at the end of `onResume()`?

Comment: i don't think so that it will help. are you sure about that? Because if we create and show it in onResume method, it will not work when i click on Share tab. don't you think so?